# QT::waitForBytesWritten() not working

Tags: c++, qt, sockets

I'm new in Qt and decided to create chat program. From the server side everytime someone connects it sends string `add=name` to every client to notify them that new client has connected, and to this connected client i send `syn=N` which means that instead of N it would be every clients name that was connected before this client connected. Here is my code:

```
void MainWindow::add_or_delete_from_listview(QString name, User *user, bool ad)
{
  if(ad)
    {
       sync(user);
       name = set_string(name);
       user_buffer << user;
       list << name;
       ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("Name: "+name+" ip:"+user->get_socket()->peerAddress().toString()+" got connected");
       model->setStringList(list);
       send_to_all("add="+name);

    }
    else
    {
       name = set_string(name);
       user_buffer.removeOne(user);
       list.removeOne(name);
       ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText("Name: "+name+" ip:"+user->get_socket()->peerAddress().toString()+" got disconnected");
       model->setStringList(list);
       send_to_all("del="+name);
    }

}

void MainWindow::send_to_all(QString text)
{
   int i = 0;
   for(; i<user_buffer.count(); i++)
   {
      qDebug() <<  user_buffer[i]->get_socket()->write(text.toLatin1());
   }
}


void MainWindow::sync(User* user)
{
   QString sync_me ="";

   for(int i = 0; i<user_buffer.count(); i++)
   {
       if(user_buffer[i]->getname() == user->getname())
       {
          continue;
       }

       sync_me+="syn="+user_buffer[i]->getname();
       qDebug() << user->get_socket()->write(sync_me.toLatin1());
       user->get_socket()->waitForBytesWritten(-1);
       sync_me.clear();
   }
}
```

With the boolean `ad` i determine if client connected or disconnected, So my problem is that, say client connected with the name A and there is already in chat with the name B and C, sometimes (not always) client A gets string `syn=Bsyn=C` instead of `syn=B` and `syn=C` separately which means that i'm doing something wrong with function`waitForBytesWritten`. I hope you can help. sorry if my question is silly. Thanks.

**P.S**
from the client side I'm using

```
QString text = sock->readAll().simplified();
qDebug() << text;

if(text.startsWith("msg="))
{
   emit  action_happened("msg=", text);
}

if(text.startsWith("add="))
{
    emit action_happened("add=", text);
}
if(text.startsWith("syn="))
{
    emit action_happened("syn=", text);
}
if(text.startsWith("del="))
{
    emit action_happened("del=", text);
}
```

and by the beginning of the input I'm determining how to handle it

Comment: You should add control characters to separate messages (say, a newline) instead of relying on the data being sent, or received, in certain chunks. socks->readAll() on the receiver side might return partial data, for example.

Comment: is that the only way?

Comment: AFAIK yes. You have no control over in which chunks the data is received, so relying on the chunks you send them in won't work reliably. Think of it as stream, not a set of packages.